# JS закрывает Html тег DIV

Tags: javascript, html

Оборачиваю массив в Html тег  назначая его переменной inputFieldB, но он в этой переменной сразу закрывается. Как предотвратить закрытие тега  в переменной inputFieldB а закрывать в переменной inputFieldE.

```js
///Открытие тега   
let inputFieldB = `<div class = "row" id = "${parameter.id}" style = "display:none;">`;

        specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputFieldB);


///Массив начало
      parameter.attributes.forEach(atr => {



        if (atr.type === "free") typeElement = 'input';
        if (atr.type === "real") typeElement = 'input';
        if (atr.type === "singleselect") typeElement = 'select';
        if (atr.type === "multiselect") typeElement = 'select';

        const element = document.createElement(typeElement);
        element.id = atr.id;

        if (atr.type === 'input') element.type = "free";

        if (atr.type === 'input') element.type = "real";

        let selElement = document.createElement('span');


        if (atr.options.length > 0 && atr.type === 'singleselect') {
          atr.options.forEach(opt => {
            element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value = "${opt.id}">${opt.name_rus}</option>`);
          })
        }

        if (atr.options.length > 0 && atr.type === 'multiselect') {
          element.multiple="multiple";
          atr.options.forEach(opt => {
            element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value = "${opt.id}">${opt.name_rus}</option>`);
          })
        }



        let inputField =
        `
        <div class = "row">
        <span  class="col-md-2">${atr.name_rus}: </span>
        ${element.outerHTML}&nbsp;${selElement.outerHTML}
        </div>
        `;
        specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputField);



      });
      
///Массив конец

        let inputFieldE = `</div>`;

        specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputFieldE);
        
///Закрытие тега
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) добавляет **HTML**, а не просто строку. Соответственно при разборе первой строки

```
let inputFieldB = `<div class = "row" id = "${parameter.id}" style = "display:none;">`
```

браузер перед вставкой разберет строку и добавит недостающий закрывающие теги.

В данном случае, проще собрать одну большую строку и вставить ее в `specification` за один раз.

Либо отказаться от `.insertAdjacentHTML` в пользу работы с непосредственно элементами и добавлять их с помощью метода [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Например так:

```
///Открытие тега   
let inputFieldB = `
<div class = "row" id = "${parameter.id}" style = "display:none;">${
    ///Массив начало
    parameter.attributes.map(atr => {
        if (atr.type === "free") typeElement = 'input';
        if (atr.type === "real") typeElement = 'input';
        if (atr.type === "singleselect") typeElement = 'select';
        if (atr.type === "multiselect") typeElement = 'select';

        const element = document.createElement(typeElement);
        element.id = atr.id;

        if (atr.type === 'input') element.type = "free";

        if (atr.type === 'input') element.type = "real";

        let selElement = document.createElement('span');
    
        if (atr.options.length > 0 && atr.type === 'singleselect') {
            atr.options.forEach(opt => {
                element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value = "${opt.id}">${opt.name_rus}</option>`);
        })
    }

        if (atr.options.length > 0 && atr.type === 'multiselect') {
            element.multiple="multiple";
            atr.options.forEach(opt => {
                element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value = "${opt.id}">${opt.name_rus}</option>`);
        })
    }
        let inputField =
            `
            <div class = "row">
                <span  class="col-md-2">${atr.name_rus}: </span>
                ${element.outerHTML}&nbsp;${selElement.outerHTML}
            </div>
            `;
        return inputField;
    }).join('')
}      
</div>`;

specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputFieldB);
        
///Закрытие тега
```

Comment: C .join(''); ругается Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing } in template expression на строку parameter.attributes.map(atr => {  Но если убрать  .join(''); то все элементы массива разделены запятыми.

Comment: @DenisMamedom, лишняя `;` после join была. Поправил

Comment: Спасибо все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создавать элемент методом `createElement()`, а вставлять его в `specifications` с помощью `outerHTML`.

Применять такой подход, мне кажется, эффективнее, чем бороться с автозакрытием тега.

```js
let inputFieldB = document.createElement("div");
inputFieldB.style.display = "none";
inputFieldB.classList.add("row");
inputFieldB.id = parameter.id;



///Массив начало
      parameter.attributes.forEach(atr => {



        if (atr.type === "free") typeElement = 'input';
        if (atr.type === "real") typeElement = 'input';
        if (atr.type === "singleselect") typeElement = 'select';
        if (atr.type === "multiselect") typeElement = 'select';

        const element = document.createElement(typeElement);
        element.id = atr.id;

        if (atr.type === 'input') element.type = "free";

        if (atr.type === 'input') element.type = "real";

        let selElement = document.createElement('span');


        if (atr.options.length > 0 && atr.type === 'singleselect') {
          atr.options.forEach(opt => {
            element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value = "${opt.id}">${opt.name_rus}</option>`);
          })
        }

        if (atr.options.length > 0 && atr.type === 'multiselect') {
          element.multiple="multiple";
          atr.options.forEach(opt => {
            element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option value = "${opt.id}">${opt.name_rus}</option>`);
          })
        }



        let inputField =
        `
        <div class = "row">
        <span  class="col-md-2">${atr.name_rus}: </span>
        ${element.outerHTML}&nbsp;${selElement.outerHTML}
        </div>
        `;
        inputFieldB.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputField);



      });
      
///Массив конец


specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputFieldB.outerHTML);
```

Comment: let inputField объявлена локально для вывода элементов массива, поэтому перенести не получится.

Comment: Вывод данных у меня инициализирует innerHTML, как я понимаю он автоматически закрывает все теги.

Comment: @DenisMamedom хорошо, тогда можно создать элемент через `createElement`, задать ему атрибуты класса, id, style вначале кода, тогда вставить inputField можно в новый элемент, а элемент уже в `specifications`

Comment: Код выдает на странице вместо массива в div  - [object HTMLDivElement]
Если  вместо
 specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputFieldB);
указываю
 specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputFieldB.innerHTML); 
то выдается массив без объявленного DIV

Comment: @DenisMamedom у меня заработало так - `specifications.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', inputFieldB.outerHTML)`

Comment: Спасибо, проверил, такой вариант тоже рабочий.